# Blazor WebAssembly Jquery methods is not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a project with the help of Blazor web assembly and jquery "On" method is not working and getting below error

[image]

I have already added jquery min file and js file which have my method that not working

[image]

Error line in java script which is available in custom.js

[image]

Comment: @Arun, "placeholder" has no vale outside the "if" -you has malpositioned the `}` of the "if", you should write `if(..){var placeholder=..;placeholder.on('click',function (ev){...})}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you used js interop?by calling your js method inside razor page
just call your method like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
@code{
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "inititCustomDropdwon");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No, I think the js file is already register at the page

Comment: Yes but also you need to call it inside razor page